# Does angularJS modelizer fetch provide a way to specify an onSuccess handler?

Tags: angularjs, fetch

Is there a way to specify an "onSuccess" handler when using Angular-modelizer fetch?  I looked at the angular-modelizer-0.2.24 source implementation of "fetch"
but the Javascript in there is boggling my mind...  Does anyone have sample code?
I would prefer not to use a $future or "promise"; I would like to treat the fetch as synchronous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some further research I figured this out; the first callback function is the "success" path, and the second callback is the error path.  Code sample included.
Given that the underlying AJAX call is asynchronous, I believe that the prevalent current pattern is to use $q and $promise, so that is what I have done.

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
    var retModel = undefined; 

    //modelizer fetch
    myModelObject.fetch(config).then(
            //1st function is the "success" function
            function(response) {
                console.log ("Fetch success path");     
                retModel = response;
                deferred.resolve(retModel);
            },  
            //2nd function is the error function.    
            function(errResponse) {
                console.log ("Error on fetch");
                deferred.reject(errResponse);
                //ErrorService.buildErrors(errResponse);                
            }
    );

    return deferred.promise;
```